# startmonitoringsignificantlocationchanges and querying the network

Tags: ios, networking, background

I've written a geo-fencing iOS app that uses startmonitoringsignificantlocationchanges to trigger an action that requires network query.  It does not work reliably because sometimes the network delay causes the app to be terminated.  I do realize that the documentation says, iOS may terminate the app if I try to do network query that takes too long:

> "If you leave this service running and your application is subsequently suspended or terminated, the service automatically wakes up your application when new location data arrives. At wake-up time, your application is put into the background and given a small amount of time to process the location data. Because your application is in the background, it should do minimal work and avoid any tasks (such as **querying the network**) that might prevent it from returning before the allocated time expires. If it does not, your application may be terminated."

Is there an alternative way to start network query in the background when iOS launches my app as a result of entering a region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to call beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler. See here:

http://www.mindsizzlers.com/2011/07/ios-background-location/